# Strange output when running PHP command line syntax check(-l) on Windows

Tags: php, windows

I ran PHP syntax check with `php -l` on a Windows 8.1 machine against this file:

**test.php**:

```
<?php
echo '
```

and the output looks like this:

```
' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in test.php on line 2
Errors parsing test.php
```

But when I tried that on a VM running CentOS 6.5, the output was normal:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in test.php on line 2
Errors parsing test.php
```

As you can see, the result generated under Windows is chopped.
I was using PHP 5.5.11 in both case. What's the issue here?

I also tried PHP version 5.5.12, 5.4.27 and 5.3.27, only 5.3.27 produced a normal result instead of a chopped one.

Comment: can you please put some more code spinet here?

Comment: `echo '` is not a valid syntax.. what do you expect ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I expect the syntax checker to produce a correct syntax check result. Please note that I wasn't running the code, I was running **syntax check** against it.

Comment: @RahulK I don't really have more code to show you. 'test.php' is all and it is intended for testing the syntax checker.

Answer (score 0):

you should close your '

```
echo ' .... ';
```

try to look on magic cotes configuration it's may help you

or try :

```
echo " .... ";
```

Comment: FYI : This website uses English as the native language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I'm asking. Please see my comment to ShankarDamodaran.